# How to fix this issue on my website (This site is down for maintenance)

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla3.0, joomla1.5

I am having this issue with my website it is displaying this message on my website (This site is down for maintenance.
Please check back again soon.) I try to login to my admin this is the message am getting (Your account has either been blocked or you have not activated it yet.) please how can I fix this issue.

Thank You.

[image]

Comment: Are you still able to log in the administrator?

Answer (score 1):

Its not an issue, Just you have set your site in offline mode.

Go to the `administrator -> site -> Global Configuration, in that page you have to found Site Offline is set as 'Yes'. Just change this to No`

Thanks & Regards,
Kaif